# Triggering a Facebook Message Upon a Gravity Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-messenger, gravity-forms-plugin

So far, I have the Facebook Checkbox Plugin/Widget (attached/from to Chatfuel) inside of an HTML widget in a Gravity Form. It works. Everything looks good. However, it has no effect on the actual messenger platform.

```
<script> window.fbMessengerPlugins = window.fbMessengerPlugins || { init : function() { FB.init({ appId: "1678638095724206", xfbml: true, version: "v2.6" }); }, callable : [] }; window.fbMessengerPlugins.callable.push( function() { var ruuid, fbPluginElements = document.querySelectorAll(".fb-messenger-checkbox[page_id='288534304507180']"); if (fbPluginElements) { for( i = 0; i < fbPluginElements.length; i++ ) { ruuid = 'cf_' + (new Array(16).join().replace(/(.|$)/g, function(){return ((Math.random()*36)|0).toString(36)[Math.random()<.5?"toString":"toUpperCase"]();})); fbPluginElements[i].setAttribute('user_ref', ruuid) ; fbPluginElements[i].setAttribute('origin', window.location.href); window.confirmOptIn = function() { FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, { app_id:"1678638095724206", page_id:"288534304507180", ref:"b64:Z2l2ZWF3YXk=", user_ref: ruuid }); }; } } }); window.fbAsyncInit = window.fbAsyncInit || function() { window.fbMessengerPlugins.callable.forEach( function( item ) { item(); } ); window.fbMessengerPlugins.init(); }; setTimeout( function() { (function(d, s, id){ var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; } js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); }, 0); </script> <div class="fb-messenger-checkbox" origin="" page_id="288534304507180" messenger_app_id="1678638095724206" user_ref="" prechecked="true" allow_login="true" size="standard"></div>
```

After viewing the Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin) I stumbled upon this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        function confirmOptIn() {
          FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
            'app_id':'APP_ID',
            'page_id':'PAGE_ID',
            'ref':'PASS_THROUGH_PARAM',
            'user_ref':'UNIQUE_REF_PARAM'
          });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="confirmOptIn()" value="Confirm Opt-in"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is the confirmation code necessary for the message to actually fire off. When I took the code and just tested it inline on my page (rather than inside the Gravity Form) it produced a button with, as you could guess. When that button is pressed, the message fires. Keep in mind, the Gravity form with the other code is still on that same page.

Now what I need is to be able to apply this effect upon the successful submission of a Gravity Form. I'm struggling with the implementation.

I am not skilled with Javascript whatsoever. But if I had to guess, I need to put the above code for the Facebook Confirmation into the below code for it to be connected to the Gravity Forms Submission:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).bind('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, formId){
    // code to be trigger when confirmation page is loaded
});
</script>
```

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_confirmation_loaded/#source-code

I've also tested the following code to see if I can get it to work with just the click of the submit button, though even with this final product, I have been unable to successfully manage to trigger the Facebook message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gform_25 input[type=submit]').click(function () {
            function confirmOptIn() {
          FB.AppEvents.logEvent('MessengerCheckboxUserConfirmation', null, {
            'app_id':'APP_ID',
            'page_id':'PAGE_ID',
            'ref':'PASS_THROUGH_PARAM',
            'user_ref':'UNIQUE_REF_PARAM'
          });
      }
      confirmOptIn();
    });
  });
 </script>
```

I realize how confusing this post might be. I really hope it's not though, and that there's an answer somewhere out there. The main goal is to trigger a Facebook message after a Gravity Forms Submission. Thanks!

Comment: _“Granted, this is JQuery while the Facebook code is plain Javascript, so just pasting it as is won't work.”_ - wrong, of course you can execute “normal” JavaScript code inside jQuery event handler functions ... jQuery _is_ JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that it is possible. I have someone advising me who said it can't be done like that.

Comment: I have updated the original post with a new code that I feel should be working, yet still will not.